# SvelteKit Node streams are no longer supported

Tags: stream, fetch, sveltekit

Since `node-fetch` was replaced by `undici` in [#5117](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/5117) some of us encountered the error

> Node streams are no longer supported — use a ReadableStream instead

like in [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/vrdav5/sveltekit_node_adapter_node_streams_are_no_longer/)

It is not easy to reproduce, for me the error occured only in production.

This is a self-answered question in case you have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from [src/runtime/server/utils.js L46](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/dd4aaba32cf8fc658bf17ab664a5d4be60425124/packages/kit/src/runtime/server/utils.js#L46) and is thrown after checking the `_readableState` property and some type on the response body of the request.

For me the problem was that my `endpoint.ts` was returning the `fetch` directly.

```js
export async function post({request}){
  return fetch('...')
}
```

This used to work but not anymore since the `fetch` response is a complex object with the `_readableState` property. To fix this you have to consume the response and return a simpler object like

```js
export async function post({request}){
  try {
    const res = await fetch('...')
    const data = await res.json()
    return {
      status: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({...data}),
    }
  catch(error){
    return { status: 500}
  }
}
```